# IIS 7 manager not opening but working

Tags: windows-7, iis-7

I have windows 7 home premium. I have turned on IIS .Confirmed if its running by typing localhost on my address bar. It show IIS welcome message, showing its working.

However when I try to open IIS manager, nothing happens. I want to deploy my asp.net mvc 3 application on it. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 9):

For me helped focusing on the window via `Alt-Tab`, then pressing `Alt-Space` and select `Move` in the drop-down menu. After that, either drag the mouse or move with keyboard buttons. By the way, works with all windows.

**Update for Win 10**

There is another easier solution for such windows for Win 10. You can pull any available window to the left edge of the screen. Windows will expand the window to half of the screen and prompts you to choose any opened window to fill the second half. Choose the window you can't access and you're good.

[image]

Comment: Using the keyboard worked for me. The mouse would not move it into my screen.

Comment: You saved my day... I wasted so much time. I even reinstalled IIS but nothing seemed to be working (I was connecting remotely to my workstation)... your trick solved the problem

Comment: @AthAn Glad it helped :) Going to update my answer with one more solution for Win 10.